# postgresql meaning of the following syntax current_database()::information_schema.sql_identifier

Tags: postgresql

Just a quick question

In postgresql sometimes I can see syntax similar to this:

```
current_database()::information_schema.sql_identifier
```

what does that `::` means ?

Answer (score 1):

`::` is used to cast a data type into another.
there are 2 ways of casting (run-time type conversion)

```
CAST ( expression AS type )
expression::type
```

you can use either of them.
you can refer http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html for more details.